# Projection onto the space spanned by eigenfunctions in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, eigenfunctions, projection

Suppose that $\{Y_n(t)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of random functions in a Hilbert space, and $D(s,t)=\operatorname{Var}(Y_n(t),  Y_n(s))$.  Let $\{(w_i(t), \tau_i) :  i=1,2...\}$ be eigenfunction–eigenvalue pairs associated with $D(s,t)$.  To reduce the dimensionality of $Y_n(t)$, project $Y_n(t)$ onto the space spanned by the functions $\{(w_i(t), \tau_i): 1 ≤ i ≤ q\}$.

Here is what I cannot understand: according to the paper I am studying, by doing this, we can obtain
\begin{pmatrix} \langle Y_n, w_1\rangle \\ \langle Y_n, w_2\rangle \\ \vdots \\ \langle Y_n, w_q\rangle \end{pmatrix}

In fact, I am trying to understand the techniques on Hilbert space by using my understanding of the finite dimensional case, since I have not fully understood functional analysis. Considering the projection matrix in a finite vector space, $P=W(W'W)^{-1} W'=WW'$, where $W=[w_1, w_2,  \dotsc, w_q]$, so $PY_n=\langle Y_n, w_1\rangle w_1+\langle Y_n, w_2\rangle w_2+\dotsb+ \langle Y_q, w_q\rangle w_q$. I thought this result in a finite dimensional space is different from the above projection in an infinite dimensional space. I don't understand this.

Could you explain how I can understand the dimension reduction? The paper I am reading is [Horváth, L., & Reeder, R. (2012). Detecting changes in functional linear models. Journal of Multivariate Analysis, 111, 310-334.]

Thank you for reading my question :)

Comment: It looks to me like the projection you wrote down is the same as the paper is stating. The entries $<Y_n(t),w_i(t)>$ are in a location in the column that I suppose corresponds to $w_i$, so that your projection and the one in the paper are the same.

Comment: Oh, I found what I had missed! Heartily thank you! If you don't mind, could you give me a hint once more? I am struggling to project 
$\sum_{i}^{q} \sum_{j}^{p} \psi_{ij} w_i(t) \int_{0}^{1} v_j(s) X_n(s) ds$ onto the same space above which is the space spanned by the functions {$w_i(t), \; \tau_i), 1 ≤ i ≤ q$}. Could you help me to guess the projection of the equation using the same idea?